# Find x s.t. $f(x)=K$ for $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \max(0,a_ix+b_i)$ faster than binary search

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Can we find $x$ s.t. $f(x)=K$ for $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \max(0,a_ix + b_i)$ faster than binary search? We can apply binary search since $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing function. But If we consider more carefully, $f(x)$ is not only monotonically increasing function, but also convex function.

Let's prove that $f(x)$ is convex function.
$$\begin{align}
&f(x) \\
=&\sum_{i=1}^N\max(0,a_ix + b_i) \\
=&\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i\right)+\sum_{i=1}^N \max(a_ix,-b_i) \\
\end{align}$$
Since max function is convex function, the sum of max function is also convex fuction. Thus, $f(x)$ is convex function. Some method is known (for example, Dinkelbach algorithm) for finding the zero point faster than binary search using the property of convex function. In this case, does such algorithm exist ?